# get Centerpoint of Bitmap on an imageView

Tags: android, android-layout

I draw an Bitmap on an ImageView (and some other stuff). 
I don't know if this problem is too trivial, but I did nothing found solving my problem,yet.

So:
I need to get the Centerpoint auf the Bitmap after I manipulated it. 
So the Bitmap is rotated,moved and scaled.

How can I still get the CenterPoint of the BitMap on the Screen with an x/y coordinate?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following,

```
 int width=Bitmap.getWidth();
 int height=Bitmap.getHeight();

 int centerX=width/2;
 int centerY=height/2;
```

then centerX and centerY will be the center of the bitmap.